# error when trying to program the chip on stm32 f44re nucleo board

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

```
17:24:45 **** Programming project STM32_HelloWorld on chip ****

"C:\\Ac6\\SystemWorkbench\\plugins\\fr.ac6.mcu.externaltools.openocd.win32_1.23.0.201904120827\\tools\\openocd\\bin\\openocd.exe" -f stm32.flash.6462756934245305845.cfg -s "C:\\Users\\nvenk\\Workspace\\RTOS_workspace\\STM32_HelloWorld" -s "C:\\Ac6\\SystemWorkbench\\plugins\\fr.ac6.mcu.debug_2.5.0.201904120827\\resources\\openocd\\st_scripts" -c "program Debug/STM32_HelloWorld.elf verify reset " -c shutdown

Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00021-g524e8c8 (2019-04-12-08:48)

Licensed under GNU GPL v2

For bug reports, read

http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html

srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_assert_srst

Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD

adapter speed: 8000 kHz

adapter_nsrst_delay: 100

Info : clock speed 8000 kHz

Error: libusb_open() failed with LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS

Error: open failed (no matching adapter found)

in procedure 'program'

in procedure 'init' called at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 495

in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'

** OpenOCD init failed **

shutdown command invoked



17:24:46 Build Finished (took 201ms)
```

Also I do have drivers installed for stm32 board. copy pasted screen shot of my device manager below. Please help me.
[image]

Comment: I've rejected your edit of my answer. Please update your question instead if you have additional information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the log I can see that you are using OpenOCD to upload the firmware. OpenOCD doesn't use the propriertary STM drivers but the *libusb*. That's the cause of the error:

> Error: libusb_open() failed with LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS

To fix it, you will need to install a tool called [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/).

In Zadig:

1. Check *Options* / *List all devices*
2. Select the STLink in the upper combobox
3. Select *libusbK* in the combox box on the right hand side of the arrow
4. Click *Install Driver*

[image]

After the installation, it should display *libusbK* on the left hand side of the arrow as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response.